# How do I create a box for the user to enter their post code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I am creating a windows application in Visual Studio using C#.

I want to create a textbox into which the user will type their post code. The programme needs to be able to verrify that a valid entry has been entered.

I am new to programming and have tried searching google but just got even more confused.

Comment: Validating post-codes is very complicated. It depends heavily on your country and varies even wihtin countries.
Confusion is not really avoidable at this point - Post-codes are not fun to deal with

Comment: I am wanting to validate english post codes only. these have two very similar formats single letter, double number, space, single number, double letter the other format is the same except it starts with double letter instead of single.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this purpose. Simply define the postal code pattern in the control's [`Mask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Note that by itself it will only check if the input matches the expected format. If you need to check if the code is coherent with other segments of an address (for instance a ZIP code starting with 50000 isn't valid in Minnesota) you will most likely need to use an online service API.

**EDIT:**

A bit out of scope here but still a valid point: as mentionned by Benjamin, you will want validation at model level. Think of the `MaskedTextBox` control as a simple way to help the end user entering a well-formed ZIP code before it actually gets validated when committed to your model object.

Comment: The pattern for a *UK* postcode should be `>L?0a 0LL`.

Comment: You should also be validating the post code on the model and NOT just in the UI.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul that goes without saying but since the question is about input in the UI I figured it would be best to keep things in that scope.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul probably safe to say this is a homework assignment, would be surprised if the application is layered as such. Might just be confusing the OP more than helping.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul I rephrased that part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a method we have previously used to validate a british postcode... (note: we actually validate using a 3rd party API now)

```
        private bool IsPostCode(string text)
        {
            var nospace = text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
            if (nospace.Length < 6)
            {
                return false;
            }

            char[] chars = text.ToCharArray();

            if (chars[0] < 'A' || chars[0] > 'Z')
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (chars[1] < 'A' || chars[1] > 'Z')
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (chars[2] < '0' || chars[2] > '9')
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```